# Tools to develop and debug ELISP code

Tags: debugging, programming, debug

I have some experience in Emacs-LISP. Today I spent 6 hours writing LISP code that I guess-timate would have taken 1h30 to write in Python because my workflow to develop and debug is very clunky. In Python I would log successive values with `print("Stage N: " + value)` at different stages. I am looking for something better.

I give two examples below. I'm sure other people are more productive given the high reputation of LISP. What workflows do coders use for development and debugging in Emacs-LISP?

### One example

Automated testing with ERT does not indicate the line of an error. This is so strange that I made it into [its own question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54369/line-of-error-in-emacs-regression-test-ert-framework)).

### Another example

In debugging a function with an optional argument, I was unable to log that value to the `*Messages*` buffer as I could not find how to convert `t` and `nil` to string. In the `*scratch*` buffer:

```lisp
(message (concat "Value is: " (string t))) ;; concat: Wrong type argument: characterp, t

(message (concat "Value is: " (string nil))) ;; concat: Wrong type argument: characterp, nil

(message (concat "Value is: " t)) ;; message: Wrong type argument: sequencep, t

(message (concat "Value is: " nil))
"Value is: "
```

Comment: The question is too broad, and possibly opinion-based (e.g. what is a "productive framework"?). Please try to pose a specific question that is likely to solicit useful, specific answers.

Comment: Simply `(message "Value is %s" whatever). I suggest `C-h f message`.

Comment: One possiblity is [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug).

Comment: @Drew I edited the question to request less of an opinion and more to learn what other people use.

Comment: @JeanPierre Yes, that did it, and therefore `(format "%s" t)` also works.

Comment: @NickD Today I learned about Emacs built-in debugger. I'll test it the next time I write some convoluted Elisp code.

Comment: FYI python also has a perfectly good debugger, `pdb`.  (The last time I was using python, the third-party `ipdb` was a much nicer user interface to it.)  You can read about the Emacs debuggers (plural) at `C-h i g (elisp)Debugging`

Comment: I culled the bits from the comments above and started a  Community answer. Feel free to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the beginnings of a list of useful techniques culled from the comments. Please add any others that you find useful by editing this answer:

- The elisp analog of sprinkling printfs in a program to show values of variables: `(message "Value is %s" whatever)`.
- [Using a debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging): possibilities include the [Lisp Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger.html#Debugger), and [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug).